# jasperreport $v page_number not working

Tags: pagination, jasper-reports, page-numbering

I am trying, to put in report pagination
But! I have new report on each page, this is the problem
page_number field show me always "1" on every page
I think it happens because on each page new report
So could you help me
P.S: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Add Variable `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` and set Evaluation time to `Now` and if you want the total number of pages set Evaluation time to `Report`

Comment: I set eTime on Now but it did not help, they always shows 1 of 1 , as i sad before i think it happens because, my code create many reports in one (for example pdf) document and each report have one page

Answer (score 0):

**Following steps resolved this for me.**

1. In the Project Explorer, open the jrxml of the page from where you want the numbers to start from 1.
2. In the design tab, double-click the text field containing the page number element. Example: **$V{PAGE_NUMBER}**.
3. In the Properties window, in the Expression field, type **$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}**.
4. Click Finish.
5. Check the preview.